# Top half of every letter (all text) cut off

Tags: text, crystal-reports

On a client machine, all of the TextFields are displayed with the text cut in half, vertically.

[image: Example]

A few fields that display correctly are Formula fields or have a height increased for testing purposes.

This bug started happening without any update of my software, so must be something inside the machine of the user.

It works elsewhere.

The client uses a XP SP3, the only thing that happened (what I can see, using the event viewer) is that a Office 2007 installation failed and after that all reports have this problem.

Comment: Formula fields are overlapping text fields.... in design where did you place the both formula and text fields?

Comment: I got the answer from another forum. It isin't the overlapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this report works everywhere except this client, it must be some sort of wrong config with in the client machine.

So, I replaced the printer default with another printer and the reports started displaying everything as it should.

**So a wrong default printer was the problem.**